# How can i convert links to https when server providing https?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, https, web

I have got wild card SSL installed. I want to serve links as https when https version of the site is fetched

Is this possible somehow ?

All links currently embedded as

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.monstermmorpg.com/js_files/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

Any quick solution possible ? thanks a lot

I am using asp.net 4.5 website

Comment: protocol relative hrefs; <script src=”//static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the http:// portion and use instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//static.monstermmorpg.com/js_files/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

It should request based on the current scheme being used.

Comment: yes this would work if static was not a subdomain but domain itself :D i made a cokieless subdomain to serve css, js, image content.

Comment: This solution should work for domains and also sub-domains. Could you elaborate a little on what you want to achieve?

Comment: I've tested this here on my dev machine with Localhost and it works fine. Have you tested that your dev machine responds to https:// ?

Comment: you know it doesnt parse urls at localhost